# A function takes a string of numbers and inserts a dash before and after each odd digit: The exception: string cannot begin or end with '-'

Tags: python

The task: Write a method that takes in a number and returns a string, placing single dash before and after each odd digit. There is one exception: don't start or end the string with a dash.

Here is what I have:

```
num = "32343"
dash = ""

for digit in num:
    if int(num[0]) % 2 != 0:
        dash = digit + "-"
    else:
        dash += digit
    if int(digit) % 2 != 0:
        dash += "-" + digit + "-"
    else:
        dash += digit
    if int(num[-1]) % 2 != 0:
        dash += "-" + digit
    else:
        dash += digit

print(dash)
```

It is printing "3--3--3"

If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: If functioning properly, it should be printing "3-2-3-4-3"

Comment: Incidentally, why the "double negatives" in your "if" statements? Rather than if int(num[0]) % 2 != 0: ... else... just make it: if int(num[0]) % 2 == 0: ... else...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just a series of if - else cases to consider, which is quite self-explanatory:

```
num = "32343"
string = ""
for i in xrange(0,len(num)):
    if i == 0 and i == len(num) - 1 and int(num[i]) % 2 != 0:
        string = num[i]
    elif i == 0 and int(num[i]) % 2 != 0:
        string = num[i] + "-"
    elif i == len(num) - 1  and int(num[i]) % 2 != 0:
        string = string + "-" + num[i]
    elif int(num[i]) % 2 !=0:
        string =  string + "-" + num[i] + "-"
    elif int(num[i]) % 2 == 0:
        string = string + num[i]

print string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in various ways using splicing (the [:] syntax) but my first crack at it would be via a generator. Your use of mod (%) is a great start, but you can avoid several elif using string formatting and implicit else's.

edit: I noticed you should still have a trailing - on the first number and a preceding - on the end number as per example. Using splicing, I remove these in the revision and no longer yield 0th and last elements unaltered:

```
def dash(num):
    """ add surrounding -'s to any digit in num which is odd """
    for n in num:
        if int(n) % 2 != 0:
            n = "-%s-" % n
        yield n

def remove_bookends(_str):
    """ if - is at the start or end of _str, remove it """
    if _str[0] is "-":
        _str = _str[1:]
    if _str[-1] is "-":
        _str = _str[:-1]
    return _str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = "32343"
    _str = "".join([n for n in dash(num)])
    _str = remove_bookends(_str)
    print _str
```